How to handle wildcard searches and accent insensitive searches in Azure Search?
As stated in the documentation, wildcard queries are not being analyzed (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-1-fielded-search).
We have custom analyzers in our search index (e.g.for AsciiFolding). However, any query with an asterisk (*) at the end and a search term that contains an Umlaut (ä, ö, ü) or French characters (e.g., é, è, â) returns no results, because in wild card queries only lowercasing is applied.
Example:

Desirée*
Häuser*

The following examples work (without the asterisk):

Desirée, Desiree
Häuser, Hauser

We want to support searches for partial terms like Des or Häu, and we have many search fields, so adding a custom analyzer for each of them seems excessive.
As a workaround, we currently perform the following queries, to benefit from both worlds:

("Desirée" or "Desirée*")
("Häuser" or "Häuser*")

Any advice on how to handle wildcard searches with special characters more efficiently would be highly appreciated. Or maybe we should just use custom analyzers on all our fields more thoroughly that are searchable?

add multiple languages and scoringProfilesThis the sample   "search": "pets allowed",   "searchFields": "Tags, Description_fr",   "select": "HotelName, Tags, Description_fr",   "scoringProfile": "frenchFirst",   "count": "true"  
